# What's different between pre in and into?

Tags: meaning

When I suffer on the facebook, I see a person uses the sentence "Cut lemon in half"
So, I wonder is it the same meaning as the sentence "cut lemon into half"
and what's exactly the meaning of sentence "cut an apple to half"?

Answer (score 1):

You "cut in half"
and "cut into halves'

They're practically the same. In the first instance, the emphasis is on the act of cutting whereas the second focuses on the end result of having two halves.

I don't think "cut to half" is grammatical in this context.